# Proxying internal traffic to Azure Service Bus

Tags: rabbitmq, azureservicebus, rabbitmq-shovel

What I'm trying to achieve is interoperability between RabbitMQ clients in an internal network, and Azure Service Bus consumers running in Azure.

The RabbitMQ clients need to publish and subscribe, as do the Azure Service Bus consumers - so I need some kind of 'bi-directional proxy'. A diagram of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
                                      +
                    Internal network  |  Azure
                                      |
                                      |
+--------+                            |                               +----------+
| Client +---+                        |                           +---+ Consumer |
+--------+   |                        |                           |   +----------+
             |                        |                           |
             | +-----------------+    |    +-------------------+  |
             +-+ RabbitMQ Broker +---------+ Azure Service Bus +--+
             | +-----------------+    |    +-------------------+  |
             |                        |                           |
+--------+   |                        |                           |   +----------+
| Client +---+                        |                           +---+ Consumer |
+--------+                            |                               +----------+
                                      |
                                      |
                                      |
                                      +
```

AFAIK, both the RabbitMQ broker and Azure Service Bus can do AMQP 1.0. I've looked at the rabbit shovel plugin, but I *think* this would only handle publishing of messages from the internal clients to Azure, and wouldn't allow the clients to subscribe to messages published by the Azure consumers? Or have I got this wrong, and shovel will work for this?

If shovel won't work, is there any other way to achieve this

Comment: https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/bridge/ is designed for exactly these kinds of scenarios

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got a response from a couple of Pivotal engineers, over on the [rabbitmq-users](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rabbitmq-users/MzhRt_L2BFo) group.

I was incorrect - shovel is actually bi-directional, acting as both publisher and consumer, so you can both send *and* receive messages from a remote broker.

I should then be able to fulfill my requirements by installing and configuring the [shovel plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/shovel.html) in the internal RabbitMQ broker.

There are some gotchas when connecting to an Azure Service Bus broker though:

1. If you need to use a queue with sessions, you should use the [`GroupId`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-amqp-protocol-guide) property for the session ID (`amqpMessage.Properties.GroupId = mySessionId`)
2. If you need to use a queue with partitions, you should use the [`x-opt-partition-key`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-amqp-request-response) annotation for the partition ID (`amqpMessage.MessageAnnotations[new Symbol("x-opt-partition-key")]  = myPartitionKey`)

Comment: @RobBowman in theory it should work, but I couldn't get it to. I spent a lot of time messing with the Shovel plugin, but never got it to even connect to Service Bus. I see there have been some relevant [PRs since](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-amqp1.0-client/pull/20), and various questions over on [rabbitmq-users](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/rabbitmq-users/Shovel$20Service$20Bus;context-place=topic/rabbitmq-users/MzhRt_L2BFo) where it looks like others have got it working

Comment: This answer has helped me a lot. I've followed [Microsoft guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-integrate-with-rabbitmq) and it worked for me :)